# Chrome freezes every minute on Ubuntu installed on USB stick

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, usb-installation

I have installed Ubuntu on a USB 3.0 stick. Everything seems to work fine and quite fluently except for the my chrome browser so far. It keeps on freezing every minute for about 10 seconds. It seems to be rather independent from my browsing behavior since some packages load without interruption and then after the page has been load the browser may freeze for several seconds.

Does anyone know if chrome has a habit of writing large files every minute into come cache or something similar? If yes is there a way to switch it off somehow?

Comment: Could it be caused by swapping activity?

Comment: Well I followed the instructions on this page `https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Installation_auf_Flashmedien/` and set `vm.swappiness=0` in the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` then I restarted. I'm not sure if I could do anything else... Maybe I could erase my swap partition completely? Does Ubuntu still work then? I would be fine having no swap. I don't see a point of having it anyway... my RAM is 8 Gig, so should be enough

Comment: Don't erase your swap partition, do `sudo swapoff -a` to disable swapping. With 8 Gb you should be fine. Tell us if you see a difference.

Comment: I thinks its getting better. But still the system freezes from time to time. I will check if I have formatted the USB stick with the wrong erasureblocksize, I let you know if thats solving the performance issues...